# Git (Credential Manager) not found after deleting /home/.dotnet

Tags: command-line, bash, git, dotnet

Recently I uninstalled .NET (which was mistakenly installed to /home/.dotnet/ with the [dotnet install script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script)) by deleting the `/home/.dotnet/` folder from my Ubuntu 22.04 machine. I have a repo which I am trying to `git push` my changes to remote, which was authenticated and worked fine (without any username or password) before I uninstalled .NET. However, now running this command gives this message:

```
$ git push
/home/yee/.dotnet/tools/git-credential-manager get: 1: /home/yee/.dotnet/tools/git-credential-manager: not found
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

```
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

It seems like .NET left some residue when I simply deleted the folder it was in. Checking `$PATH`, I get
`/home/yee/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/yee/.dotnet/tools:/home/yee/.cabal/bin:/home/yee/.ghcup/bin`

I ran `export PATH=/home/yee/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/yee/.cabal/bin:/home/yee/.ghcup/bin` to remove `.dotnet` from PATH, but the `git push` command still gives the same result. I also searched `/etc/profile` and `~/.bashrc` for `.dotnet`, and deleted `dotnet.sh` in `/etc/profile.d`, then rebooted the computer, but still the same problem occurs.

How can I fix my `git` installation?

Answer (score 0):

.NET had changed my Git configuration to use itself as the credential manager, which then broke when I deleted it.

To fix, I ran the first two commands as per [this issue](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/3796)

````
$ git config --global 'credential.https://github.com.helper' ''
$ git config --global --add 'credential.https://github.com.helper' '!gh auth git-credential'```
````